# Does mysql_real_escape_string() FULLY protect against SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

On http://www.justinshattuck.com/2007/01/18/mysql-injection-cheat-sheet/?akst_action=share-this , there is a section that claims you can bypass mysql_real_escape_string with certain Asian character encodings

> Bypassing mysql_real_escape_string() with BIG5 or GBK
>
> "injection string"
>   に関する追加情報：
>
> the above chars are Chinese Big5

Is this really true? And if so, how would you protect your website against this, if you had no access to prepared statements?

Comment: justinshattuck.com gives me a malware warning on Chrome, maybe his site got hacked too.

Comment: The characters in your injection string are not really BIG5.  Some vendors extended BIG5 to include Japanese kana, but the standard does not include kana.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to Stefan Esser, *"`mysql_real_escape_string()` [is] not safe when `SET NAMES` is used."*

His explanation, [from his blog](http://www.suspekt.org/2008/09/18/slides-from-my-lesser-known-security-problems-in-php-applications-talk-at-zendcon/):

> SET NAMES is usually used to switch the encoding from what is default to what the application needs.
>   This is done in a way that `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn’t know about this. This means if you switch to some multi byte encoding that allows backslash as 2nd 3rd 4th… byte you run into trouble, because `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn’t escape correctly. UTF-8 is safe…
>
> Safe way to change encoding is `mysql_set_charset`, but that is only available in new PHP versions

He does mention that UTF-8 is safe, though.

Comment: "UTF-8 is safe…" leads to another rarely-known monster: input encoding security. E.g. do you check if the input (e.g. GET/POST/COOKIE/...) is really UTF-8? Is automatic input encoding checking and conversion active (either at server level or app level)? Etc.

Answer (score 19):

This is a MySQL server bug that was reportedly fixed way back in May 2006.

See:

- [MySQL bug #8303](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8303): String literals with multi-byte characters containing \ are lexed incorrectly
- [MySQL Bug #8317](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8317): Character set introducer in query fails to override connection character set
- [MySQL Bug #8378](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8378): String escaped incorrectly with client character set 'gbk'
- MySQL 5.1.11 [changelog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/news-5-1-11.html).

The bug was reported fixed in MySQL 4.1.20, 5.0.22, 5.1.11.

If you use 4.1.x, 5.0.x, or 5.1.x, make sure you have upgraded at least to the minor revision numbers.

As a workaround, you can also enable the SQL mode [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) which disables backslash as a quote-escape character.

Comment: If you use `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` then you [**must not** quote your literals using double-quote `"` characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23277864/623041).

Comment: @eggyal, can I ask why you say that? Try `SELECT "O""Hare";`

Comment: Follow the link!  In `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` mode, `mysql_real_escape_string()` only doubles `'` characters and not `"` characters!

Comment: @eggyal, ah, thanks, that's good to know. Well, one should use the standard `'` for string delimiters anyway.

Comment: Indeed, which is why in that post I recommend setting `ANSI_QUOTES` mode to enforce such behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it only doesn't work if you use SQL to change the char encoding.

Answer (score 1):

As others have demonstrated, [`mysql_real_escape_string()` can be bypassed in obscure edge cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2224584). That's one known strategy for bypassing the escaping logic, but there could be other unknown vulnerabilities that have not been discovered yet.

The simple and effective way to [prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide) is to use **prepared statements** where you can, and a very *strict* whitelist where you can't.

Prepared statements, when actually used and not emulated by the PDO driver, are provably secure (at least with regards to SQL injection), as they solve a fundamental problem with application security: they separate the **data** from the **instructions** that operate on the data. They're sent in separate packets; the parameterized values never have a chance to taint the query string.

It's 2015. Don't escape and concatenate anymore. You should still validate your inputs according to application (and business) logic, but just use prepared statements.