# Bypassing mysql_real_escape_string's protection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Some dude challenged me to sql-inject his code. He said the PHP function in the title should suffice for this case.

```
$var = 'my malevolent input will be in here';
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$var'";

mysql_query($sql);
```

I can't seem to bypass the single-quote escaping. What should I use as a value for $var? *Can* I use something?

<kbd>Thanks, as always</kbd>

Comment: suspicious challenge. Didn't he challenge you to break into Fort Knox also?

Comment: @Col my neighbour challenged me to break into his flat before he left for his holiday. Any tools or ideas? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220182/does-mysql-real-escape-string-fully-protect-against-sql-injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is considered to be safe for any input unless the character encoding is not set properly by using [`mysql_client_encoding`](http://php.net/mysql_client_encoding).

Comment: Do you happen to know links to specific exploit examples for a mis-set character set off the top of your head? (No need to dig, just curious)

Comment: @Pekka: [Chris Shiflett’ “`addslashes()` Versus `mysql_real_escape_string()`”](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) has an example.

Answer (score 2):

While there may be esoteric exploits in certain server versions under certain conditions and such, as far as I know, using `mysql_real_escape_string()` in this way is generally considered safe.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in code:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'id' = '$var'";`

Should be

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'id' = '".$var."'";`

If you a not sure if id is an integer or a string.

If you are sure that id is always an integer, then:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'id' = ".intval($var)`

And you will be safe with `mysql_real_escape_string();` ^_^

Comment: oops. haha ) was browsing saw weird code and posted.. http://www.topito.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/code-31.gif