# Is mysql_real_escape_string enough to Anti SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

In PHP Manual, there is a note:

> Note: If this function is not used to
>   escape data, the query is vulnerable
>   to SQL Injection Attacks.

Is this enough to anti sql injection? If not, could you give an example and a good solution to anti sql injection?

Comment: See [Does mysql_real_escape_string() FULLY protect against SQL injection?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220182/does-mysql-real-escape-string-fully-protect-against-sql-injection).

Comment: definitely a duplicate of above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is usually enough to avoid SQL injection. This does depend on it being bug free though, i.e. there's some small unknown chance it *is* vulnerable (but this hasn't manifested in the real world yet). A better alternative which completely rules out SQL injections on a conceptual level is [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Both methods entirely depend on your applying them correctly; i.e. neither will protect you if you simply mess it up anyway.

Comment: just to clarify: there is also a chance that PDO emulates prepared queries (for mysql) and doesn't use native mysql ones. There is no such declaration in php documentation (or I cannot found one).

Comment: "PDO will emulate for drivers that don't support them" --- is not enough, because: a) installed (old) libmysql can don't support prepared; b) PDO still can don't use native prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this is a solid way to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, that i think you can attack from a URL.

Comment: You can also, always restrict who can access what on your database, and who has what privileges.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

If you're using the traditional [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) then running all of your data through `mysql_real_escape_string()` is enough.

Comment: Parameterized queries are also available in the `PDO` extensions