# PHP / MySQL - Search query

Tags: php, wordpress, mysql

I need help making a search query for comments (it's for a WordPress site).

the comments are retrieved this way- if user is logged in:

```
       $comments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
       SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = %d
       AND (comment_approved = '1' OR (user_id = %d AND comment_approved = '0'))
       ORDER BY comment_date_gmt", $post->ID, $user_ID));
```

if not:

```
       $comments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
       SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = %d
       AND (comment_approved = '1' OR (comment_author = %s
         AND comment_author_email = %s AND comment_approved = '0'))
       ORDER BY comment_date_gmt",
       $post->ID, wp_specialchars_decode($comment_author,ENT_QUOTES),
       $comment_author_email));
```

so I how can I filter comments that contain a specific search string, like `$_GET['search_query']` ?

this is WP's [database structure](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png). The search string I'm looking for is in `comment_content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use LIKE

```
 $comments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
       SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_content LIKE ('%$_GET['search_query']%')
and comment_post_ID = %d
       AND (comment_approved = '1' OR (user_id = %d AND comment_approved = '0'))
       ORDER BY comment_date_gmt", $post->ID, $user_ID));
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try. btw what does the percentage sign do before and after $_GET ?

Answer (score 1):

You can put them all in an array and use array_search:

http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

You can also use wp google search query widge. i used it before and
it's great:

http://www.lautr.com/wp-google-search-query-widget-wordpress-plugin

Comment: but wouldn't it be faster to only get the comments that have that search string? I'm mean less database usage

Comment: check the wp google search query widge. it suited perfectly for wordpress

Answer (score 1):

> thanks, I'll try. btw what does the percentage sign do before and after $_GET ?

It'll match any number of characters before and after the search string.

Comment: thanks :D another queston: how should I escape the $_POST variable? is `mysql_real_escape_string` enough?

Comment: I honestly do not know, I use PDO prepared statements, have only recently needed to use MySQL. You can however, read the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171115/is-mysql-real-escape-string-enough-to-anti-sql-injection) regarding the matter.