# PHP - highlight text from a string containing HTML

Tags: php, html, string

So I'm making a search function for comments. Someone else here helped me with the [SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443280/php-mysql-search-query).
What I also want to do is to highlight the search query text in the results.

The results are stored as HTML inside a `$variable`.
How can I wrap the search query text inside a `<span>` tag for example, without messing up the html.

for eg. the search query can be `foo bar` and the output can look like:

```
<p>bla bla foo bar bla</p>
```

so it should be something like:

```
<p>bla <span class="highlight">foo bar</span> bla bla</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more complicated than it looks. If we are searching for `foo bar` then

```
<p>bla bla foo bar bla</p>
```

will be converted into

```
<p>bla <span class="highlight">foo bar</span> bla bla</p>
```

but what about some special cases? It could be that `foo bar` is matched inside an HTML tag:

```
<p>bla bla <span class="foo bar">foo bar</span> bla</p>
```

which will be replaced as

```
<p>bla <span class="<span class="highlight">foo bar</span>">foo bar</span> bla bla</p>
```

Am I right with this? I haven't been into this issue, but I'd recommend you checking on CakePHP's docs (yeah, I know you are not using the framework--) in the Text helper, the [`highlight()`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/text-helper#method-TextHelperhighlight) method which handles HTML tags correctly. Take a look at the source, give it a shot and if it works for you, go ahead and copy it.

Comment: yes, that situations can occur. I should have mentioned that in the question. anyway I found a easier solution, using jQuery! :D

Answer (score 7):

Simple find and replace:

```
$resultHTML = str_replace($searchString, '<span class="highlight">'.$searchString.'</span>', $resultHTML );
```

Comment: Don't forget that there is a case insensitive version also... str_ireplace

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$result = "<p>Bla bla foo bar bla bla test x x x</p>";

$query = "foo bar";

// The important point here is, USE single quote ( ' ) in replacement part!!
echo preg_replace( "/($query)/", '<span class="highlight">${1}</span>', $result );
```

Comment: You can use double quotes too, just gotta escape 'em. For more info - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Answer (score 1):

```
$searchString = 'foo bar';
$searchResult = '<p>bla bla foo bar bla</p>';

var_dump(str_replace($searchString, '<span>'.$searchString.'</span>', $searchResult));

var_dump(preg_replace('/'.$searchString.'/', '<span>'.$searchString.'</span>', $searchResult));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make sure that the search term itself does not contain any HTML, you can go straight ahead and wrap it it in `"<span>"` with the help of `str_replace()`.

Note that this is one of the very rare occasions where dealing with HTML via string functions is not bad *per se*.

If the search term can contain HTML (i.e. the highlight can span over tag borders), things get a lot more complicated and you won't get away with a clever shortcut like the one above.

Comment: well there's another problem. for eg. the output can have `<img src="foo bar.jpg" />`, then the markup breaks up..

Comment: @Alex: This is true, and it's exactly the reason why using basic string manipulation is generally considered a no-no for working with HTML. It depends a lot on your data if this simplistic approach is viable or not. If the comment can contain *any* HTML, you are in the "a lot more complicated" corner very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question but I found [this](http://www.php-help.ro/php-tutorials/php-highlight-search-keywords/)

The code is built to randomly change highlight colors, but this is done through a function, so it is easy to modify to use one color:

```
     $color = '#FCB514'; //self::generate_colors();
```

---

First Post!

Answer (score 0):

text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FCD600;