# How to neutralize inputs that contain html tags?

Tags: php, mysql

I mean if someone enters `<a>gvfdg</a>` it should not show up a link. I've tried `htmlspecialchars()` but it did not helped. In PHP and MySQL.

```
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($mesaj));

$sql="INSERT INTO mesaj (Person1, Person2, mesaj)
VALUES ('$currentuser', '$id','$mesaj')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$link))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: htmlspecialchars() will help. Show the code that isn't working

Comment: To clarify, you should be using `htmlspecialchars()` at the output stage, every time you drop a text string into an HTML page. It makes no sense to be storing HTML-encoded data in the database itself.

Comment: ooh, i thought... ok. thank you very much!

Comment: Don't worry about html tags, worry about SQL injection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171115/is-mysql-real-escape-string-enough-to-anti-sql-injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call

```
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($mesaj));
```

won't work: You will need to assign the return value.

```
$mesaj = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($mesaj));
```

However, it would be better to store the data in the database in its original form, and do a `htmlspecialchars()` when you are about to *output* the data.

I am assuming that you are doing a `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$currentuser` and `$id`as well!

Comment: $currentuser comes from a session and it is an id that comes from the database which was creates as integer increment. $id = (int)$_GET['id']; if($id < 1) exit(); So I think they are okay, i guess so.

Comment: You mean to say that mysql_real_escape_string is airtight? Amazing!

Comment: @Johan no, `(int)$_GET["id"]; if ($id < 1) exit(); ` is airtight, no need for further escaping

Comment: @Pekka, not worried about 'id', very very worried about $mesaj. This looks very insecure.

Comment: @Pekka, `mysql_real_escape_string()` only does a few things, it looks too..... flimsy.

Comment: @Johan what are you talking about? Please make an example how this is unsecure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're searching for [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). However, htmlspecialchars() should work, in the sense of converting '<' and '>' into html entities so that aren't parsed by the browser.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() has no effect :/