# $_SESSION["id"] is always zero in the database

Tags: php

I have been trying to solve this issue couldn't, tried reading from asked questions but couldn't get it. I started the session and required it in another page but when ever i want to use it to insert some text base on the current session id, it is always zero in the database. Please,explain to me, maybe i miss understood it. Thanks!

```
<?php
ob_start();

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['$user_id'])  && !empty($_SESSION['$user_id']))
{
 return true;
}   
else
     return false;
?>
include.php

<?php


include ("login._form.php");
require ("include.php");
require("require.php");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST")
{
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["user"]);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["password"]);


 if(empty($username) || empty($password))
 {
    die();
 }

   $row = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username ='$username'");

   if($row === false)
   {
    echo "Query Error";
   }

  while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($row)){

      if($username == $fetch["username"] && $password == $fetch["password"])

      {
        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
        header('Location:index.php');
      }
      else

        die("user does'n exist");

}   
mysqli_close($link);
}

login.php

?>

require("include.php");
include ("yd_sendpage_form.php");
require("require.php");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST")

{
    $user_id = $_SESSION["id"];

    $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["text"]);

    if(empty($text))
    {
        die("Field Can't Be Empty!");
    }   

    $insert = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `text`(`id`, `user_id`, `text`) VALUES ('$user_id','$user_id','$text')");

}   





?>
```

yd_sendpage.php

Comment: just after this line `$user_id = $_SESSION["id"];`, add `var_dump($_SESSION["id"]);` and what does it give? if it returns `id` and not null, perhaps something to do with the `$insert = mysqli_query(..)` part..

Comment: where do you assign the value of $id ?

Comment: set `$_SESSION["id"] = $fetch['id'];`

Comment: `$_SESSION['$user_id'] !== $_SESSION['id']`

Comment: Why are you database escaping the user password?

Comment: Avoid storing unhashed passwords in the database.  See: `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Comment: @BagusTesa it returns NULL field can't be empty.

Comment: @Abdulsadeeq, so, `var_dump($_SESSION["id"]);` returns `NULL`? where did you set this `$_SESSION["id"]`?

Comment: @BagusTesa in include.php and i required it in the header of yd_sendpage.php. That's the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_SESSION["id"] was not set, so i changed $_SESSION["id"] to $_SESSION["user"] = $username in the login.php and other pages to $_SESSION["user"] and that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(isset($_SESSION['$user_id'])  && !empty($_SESSION['$user_id']))
```

to

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['id']))
```

And don't forget about [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection), your code is vulnerable to it.
[More information about SQL injection in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171115/is-mysql-real-escape-string-enough-to-anti-sql-injection)

Comment: This is only part of the problem.  The OPs file include.php, reads like an is_logged_in function, but is just left dangling there.

Comment: @Blaatpraat, i used var_dump($_SESSION["id"]) is giving me NULL field can't be empty.