# PHP mysql injection protection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, code-injection

I have written this short function to protect against my_sql injection, because of its importance I just want to double check with other's that this will function as I intend.

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {          
    $_REQUEST[$key] = stripslashes($value);
    $_REQUEST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Don't modify the superglobals. They should be left untouched. If you only ever run your own code, it's "ok". but once you start mixing in other libraries, they may expect/require untouched data, and you've now mangled things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you use `stripslashes()` because the `magic_quotes_gpc` is set? So this code will only work when `magic_quotes_gpc` is set! I'd recommend you switch it off and dont use the strislashes() call.

But note there is nothing like "universal sanitization". Let's call it just *quoting*, because that's what its all about.

When quoting, you **always quote text for *some particular output***, like:

1. string value for mysql query
2. `like` expression for mysql query
3. html code
4. json
5. mysql regular expression
6. php regular expression

For each case, you need different quoting, because each usage is present within different syntax context. This also implies that the **quoting shouldn't be made at the input into PHP, but at the particular output**! Which is the reason why features like `magic_quotes_gpc` are broken (always assure it is switched off!!!).

So, what methods would one use for quoting in these particular cases? (Feel free to correct me, there might be more modern methods, but these are working for me)

1. `mysql_real_escape_string($str)`
2. `mysql_real_escape_string(addcslashes($str, "%_"))`
3. `htmlspecialchars($str)`
4. `json_encode()` - only for utf8! I use my function for iso-8859-2
5. `mysql_real_escape_string(addcslashes($str, '^.[]$()|*+?{}'))` - you cannot use preg_quote in this case because backslash would be escaped two times!
6. `preg_quote()`

Comment: @Karolis, do you mean character encoding? I don't think you need to check input character encoding, if you have everything set properly.

Answer (score 5):

If you use PDO (properly) you don't have to worry about MySQL injection.

Sample:

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
```

[More information](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Ive seen this type of coding but never knew the purpose. I will research it so I can begin using it at the start of my next project. Thank you

Comment: This is THE best way to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a bit of sledgehammer approach. You don't need `stripslashes` unless your running magic_quotes.
Type-Casting can be more elegant when you know you want `int`, `float` or `bool`.

## Further Info:

Type-Casting: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

testing for magic quotes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php
(Thanks Karolis)

Comment: can you please link me to a resource with more information on what you propose to do

Comment: @Johnny `if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $_REQUEST[$key] = stripslashes($value);`

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly add the database connection identifier into

```
mysql_real_escape_string(..., $db_connection_identifier);
```

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

> string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier ] )

Comment: so if my connection is $con = mysql_connect("localhost"...  i should add:
$_REQUEST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$key],$con);  ?

Comment: yes, to avoid problem mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220182/does-mysql-real-escape-string-fully-protect-against-sql-injection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243657/someone-has-hacked-my-database-how-did-this-guy-do-it/4244562#4244562

Comment: The syntax diagram says that the link identifier is optional. So unless you have multiple database connections open, you don't really _need_ to add the argument explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you include arbitrary `$key`s in your query, you should escape those too.

Comment: I had not thought of that, I don't do that often. But i am glad you brought that up for the times when I do.

Answer (score 1):

Tomas's suggestion is good, but you should always keep them both in mind, so this can be great:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { // Check if magic quotes are enabled
    foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {          
       $_REQUEST[$key] = stripslashes($value);
       $_REQUEST[$key] = stripslashes($_REQUEST[$key])
    } 
} else {
    foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
      $_REQUEST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
      $_REQUEST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$key]);
    } 
}
```