# Is this the correct way to insert data into database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert user input into a database with the following code.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' ('Email', 'Username', 'Password') VALUES ($email, $username, $password)");
```

There are no errors, but the database never seems to get the code inserted. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my entire code, HTML and all

```
<?php

    DEFINE ('SERVER', 'localhost');
    DEFINE ('PASSWORD', '');
    DEFINE ('USER', 'root');

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = SHA1($_POST['pass']);

    if(isset('submitted')
    {

    if($email && $username && $password)
    {
        $to = 'email@example.com'
        $subject = 'subject'
        $body = 'there was an error connecting to the db, please check it.'
        $dbconnect = @mysql_connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD) or die("NO WORK!");
        $query = "USE practice" 
        mysql_query($query);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Email, Username, Password)
             VALUES ('$email', '$username', '$password')") or die(mysql_erorr());
    }
    }

?>
<html>

<form action = "" method = "post">
<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="email" /> <br />
<label>Desired Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pass" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Register"  />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value=1 />
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: Check your query if you have errors... 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' ('Email', 'Username', 'Password') VALUES ($email, $username, $password)") or die(mysql_erorr());

Comment: Do as @rjmcb said and check for errors, then post them here if you need more help :)

Comment: No. `'` is not a valid quote for identifiers (in either MySQL or ANSI syntax). Also, please *use placeholders* :(

Comment: No errors show, and there is still no data

Comment: Does retrieval work? Can you get data from the database? Just to make sure your code and the DB are communicating properly.

Comment: you are still not escaping the variables! This is very important (though will not solve your issue I guess). See my answer and [the link I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7043398/684229) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should also enclose the values in apostrophes, and probably also you shall not use apostrophes for table and field names, but rather backticks ` or nothing in your case!

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Email, Username, Password)
             VALUES ('$email', '$username', '$password')")
```

But also be sure to [properly escape the values of these variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7043398/684229)! Not only because of SQL injection but mostly just to assure the proper SQL syntax. Imagine user with the name O'Brian - he would have resulted in SQL error.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. Though, after I saw your response I smacked my head for not thinking of it.

Comment: @Chris, and probably also you shall not use apostrophes for table and field names, but rather backticks ` or nothing in your case!

Comment: As far as the properly escaped thing, I'm just doing this quickly to remember the way PHP works. After I've got a working application I'll fix it up.

Comment: but this is not PHP, this is affecting mysql! Try the query above.

Comment: Yup. Remember also to run the values through mysql_real_escape_string before appending them to the query string.

Comment: @iWant, that's what I wrote in my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting some errors but not displaying probably due to following line the spell error with mysql_error as mysql_erorr

```
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Email, Username, Password)
             VALUES ('$email', '$username', '$password')") or die(mysql_erorr());
```

Just try to fix that and see if you get some database errors so that it will be easy to trace out and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Also when declaring namespaces in the mySQL database. You should put backticks ` like this.
So

```
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`Email`, `Username`, `Password`)
         VALUES ('$email', '$username', '$password')") or die(mysql_erorr());
```

Otherwise, your code looks solid.

Comment: There is no issue if we miss the backticks in column names. It dont make much difference in PHP except the standards.