# mysql_real_escape_string() Different behavior with single quote

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm trying to prevent sql injections.
For this purpose I use mysql_real_escape_string().

On my local server (phpversion 5.3.2 ):

```
$string="a'b"
$newstring=mysql_real_escape_string($string);
```

`query("INSERT INTO .. ..field1='$newstring'");`

Inserting $newstring into table puts "a'b".
On another server (phpversion 5.2.10)it puts "a\'b" into table.

How can I allow inserting "a'b" and avoid injections?
I don't want to make changes to INI file and magic_quotes as it can affect other queries.
I can't use add_slashes as I will have to look for all the usages of getting the value to remove the slashes.

Comment: but magic_quotes are off on a server and off on the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled, first apply `stripslashes()` to the data. Using this function on data which has already been escaped will escape the data twice.

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $newstring = stripslashes($newstring);
}
```

Comment: The *very best* thing, however, would be to turn off magic quotes altogether. It's a thing of the past.

Comment: What if he doesn't have the rights to change php configuration of the server?

Comment: worked great for me, now the question is: "Is it safe to use this and mysql_real_escape_string?"

Comment: And I rather not change the server configs

Comment: @lvil yes, if you apply `mysql_real_escape_string()` to it afterwards, this is safe.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that you have magic_quotes enabled on one server, but not the other.
Either disable magic_quotes or change to the code:

```
$example = stripslashes($_POST['example']);      //undoes the magic_quotes
$escaped_string = mysql_real_escape_string($example); //escapes it properly.
```

A less likely scenario may occur if you have 2 connections to 2 different database server

`mysql_real_escape_string` works different depending on the connection that you have open.
If you have multiple servers and thus multiple connections, you need to run the escaping function once per connection.

Example

```
$example = "a'b";
$connectionA = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$connectionB = mysql_connect('remotehost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$escapedstringA = mysql_real_escape_string($example, $connectionA);
$escapedstringB = mysql_real_escape_string($example, $connectionB);
```

If you leave out the connection parameter in the call to `mysql_real_escape_string` both escapedstrings will be escaped using the default encoding of remotehost, which is incorrect.

This code may work incorrect:

```
$example = "a'b";
$connectionA = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$connectionB = mysql_connect('remotehost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$escapedstringA = mysql_real_escape_string($example);  //uses remotehost's encoding
$escapedstringB = mysql_real_escape_string($example);
```

Comment: Wut? If `a'b` turns into `a\'b` in the table, that has nothing to do with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: @Pekka, I do believe it can **if** you're reusing an escaped value in a wrong encoding on a server with a very different encoding, rereading the question, I agree that it much more likely that it's the awful `magic_quotes`

Answer (score 0):

This has probably nothing to do with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but your [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) setting.

The preferable thing would be to turn magic quotes off, [as even the PHP manual itself recommends.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php)

If that is really not possible, [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) is an example how to "disable" magic quotes from inside PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed magic quotes thats the problem. The only thing you can do is detect magic qoutes and strip the slashes. Theres a few scripts you can just drop in place that will work globally

check the comments here

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

If you dont want it globally,, use the if condition and the strip slashes just on that variable

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to prevent sql injections.
>   For this purpose I use mysql_real_escape_string().

Look at this question, it might be interesting for you: [Apparently there is an SQL injection bug in my PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409629/apparently-there-is-an-sql-injection-bug-in-my-php-code)

In short,  "use mysql_real_escape_string" is not sufficient to "prevent sql injections".
It is useful for the strings only, but for the other parts you need different approach. 
Refer to my earlier answer on the matter for the full details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2995163/285587