# How to make website more secured?

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

I have a question concerning the security of website. Actually I have used the queries as:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (sno, name) VALUES('', '$name')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Does this kind of coding assures the security from sql injection or others. If not what methods could we use to make our website secured?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhhhhh...no. Your code is utterly vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I am fairly new to PHP. I could not understand which one is the best way :(

Comment: you can read some answers on this site and then ask some certain question.

Answer (score 1):

Use **PDO with prepared statement and binding param**

[PDO TUTORIAL](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html)

Here's the start.

Comment: I think, you must start from most simple things. In my practice addslashes in 80% cases is all what you need). But this is my own opinion.

Answer (score 0):

To protect yourself from sql-injections use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

In your case use `mysql_real_escape_string($string)` - but this is NOT ENOUGH SECURE. PDO )

Comment: what does it mean - "this is NOT ENOUGH SECURE?" any certain vulnerability you may show?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220182/does-mysql-real-escape-string-fully-protect-against-sql-injection#answer-1220516` - here is an explanation why it is not.

Comment: PDO has the same vulnerability as well

Comment: at least out of the box, if you didn't set the encoding in the DSN or didn't set the compatibility mode off

Comment: so, it is knowledge that makes you secure, not some cargo cult "do this and be safe"

Comment: For example `index.php?ID=-1%20union%20all%20select%201000,999999999,999999999,-999999999`. `var_dump(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));` gives `-1 union all select 1000,999999999,999999999,-999999999`

Comment: you have error after that code? I have no.

Comment: there shouldn't be any errors. like you said to the OP, "in your case use mysql_real_escape_string($string)" - so, if used with their code, your imaginary input will cause no errors nor unexpected results - just 0 rows returned.

Answer (score -5):

Also you can use addslashes php function:

```
<?php
    $name = addslashes($_POST['name']);
?>
```

Comment: @itachi as a matter of fact, there is nothing essentially wrong with them

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I didn't say addlashes has something wrong. Point is  Use proper tools for appropriate fields.

Comment: addslashes is a quite proper tool. especially when compared to mysql_real_escape_string used as is

Comment: @YourCommonSense: One perfect reason not to use addlashes is this (and why it isn't a proper tool in sql making safe)... addslashes() can be tricked into creating valid multi-byte characters out of invalid ones. Whenever a multi-byte character ends in 0×5c (a backslash), an attacker can inject the beginning byte(s) of that character just prior to a single quote, and addslashes() will complete the character rather than escape the single quote. In essence, the backslash gets absorbed, and the single quote is successfully injected. This opens the door for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @itachi that's what I am talking about. mysql_real_escape_string can be tricked as well. As well as PDO prepared statement

Comment: @YourCommonSense: totally agree with you.