# PHP intval() weird results

Tags: php

I'm encountering something weird and I don't know why it is happening!

I have a URL like:

http://mysite.com/users/`USER_ID`

this user id could be `INT` and could be `STRING`, it's something like Facebook page addresses, if you call the page with page ID it loads it, also you could call it with page name like "my_page_name"

So imagine a user which it's ID is `1` and it's address is `my_name`
On my php page I need query db, but before that I need to know which column to look, `id` or `page_name`

So I came with this solution:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $id_inted = intval($_GET['id']);

    if($id == $id_inted){
    // The column which I should look into is id
    $column = 'id';
    }else{
    // The column which I should look into is page_name
    $column = 'page_name';
    }

    $query = mysql_qyery(SELECT * FROM members WHERE $column = '$id');
?>
```

So I tested it, but the results is weird, even if I call this URL:

http://mysite.com/users/`page_name`

This happens: `$column = 'id';`

I opened a new test page:

```
<?php
$real_string = 'abcdefg';
$string_inted = intval($real_string);
echo "Real String is: " . $real_string . "<br />"; 
echo "The same string as int is: " . $string_inted . "<br />"; 
if($real_string == $string_inted) echo "Weird!"; else echo "Fine...";
?>
```

and the results:

```
Real String is: abcdefg
The same string as int is: 0
Weird!
```

Why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: congratulations on managing to consistently misspell weird as wired...

Comment: @Aatch congratulations on getting to the point of the question! :-D

Comment: I did answer the question as well. I was just amazed that you managed to write 'wired' instead of 'weird' 4 times.

Comment: @Aatch I always misspell this word, I need more exercise on English thought, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is really "wired" with so called type-juggling. It is the most error-prone part of most PHP-scripts. As such, you should always stay on the safe side and use the most robust check. For example `intval("twelve")` will return 0, which is a valid integer. But also considered "false": `print if (intval("one")) ? "yup" : "nope"` will print "nope".

In this case, using `intval`, in combination with a check if the integer is larger then zero, should do the trick:

```
<?php
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

if($id > 0){
  // The column which I should look into is id
  $column = 'id';
}else{
  // The column which I should look into is page_name
  $column = 'page_name';
}

$query = mysql_qyery(SELECT * FROM members WHERE $column = '$id');
?>
```

Or, shorter:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$column = ($id > 0) ? "id" : "page_name";
$query = mysql_qyery(SELECT * FROM members WHERE $column = '$id');
```

Aso note that $_GET["id"] might not be set, which would throw a notice in your code.

And last, but certainly not least: **the [SQL-injection](https://xkcd.com/327/)**: `?id=LittleBobby';Drop table users`.

**edit** As commentor points out, there was a logical flaw in my code, stemming form the fact I tested it in *phpsh* only. I refactored it from using `is_int()` to `intval` and `> 0`. In a web-environment, $_GET["id"] is always a string; no matter what. Hence `is_int()` will always return `FALSE`.

Comment: I use mysql_real_escape_string($id), is that enough for preventing SQL Injections here?

Comment: It [probably is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220182/does-mysql-real-escape-string-fully-protect-against-sql-injection?rq=1)

Comment: `is_int` checks type of variable and `$_GET` contains only strings, so it will always return false.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: thank you for pointing out my flaw. I rewrote my  answer a little and added explanation about your point.

Comment: You're using `$id` in your SQL statement, but since you `intval` it at the beginning of your script, it will no longer contain a string in the event `$column` is determined to be `'page_name'`. Also, it's `mysql_query`. Not trying to be pedantic, but since it should serve as a working example, I think you should fix it.

Answer (score 5):

To check if numeric value is requested, use `is_numeric`.

Answer (score 2):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
Example       Name        Result

$a == $b      Equal       TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.

$a === $b     Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b,
                          and they are of the same type.
```

Your string is casted to integer because of type juggling on `==` operator and `intval()` of a string returns `0`

This explains why `$id == $id_inted` in your code evaluates to true.

If you make your test with `===` instead of `==` no type juggling will be performed.

Comment: '===' solved the problem, thanks, but still I don't get the logic that my code echos "Weird!", so my string will be 0 after inted, but why the if() statement goes to the first echo? even with your answer, 0 != 'abcdefg'

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a little odd when it comes to types.

Basically, what you are doing is parsing the string into a number (so `'abcdef'` returns 0 because it isn't a number at all), then comparing the original string to the number.

Now, I can see why you would assume that it should be false, but PHP tries to be clever. Basically, `==` will coerce types, and almost always coerces to numbers if one of it's values is a number. So it is using the same conversion that you did on the string, then comparing.

It is a better idea to use `===` which also checks types.

Answer (score 1):

The integer value of var on success, or 0 on failure. Empty arrays return 0, non-empty arrays return 1. (From php.net [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).)

intval('abcdefg') will trigger an error and the function return with 0.

Comment: exactly, that's true, but why would it's value be the same as the string!? what is the solution to the problem above?

Comment: Becouse of the type juggling PHP will convert the string to match the type with the intval-ed variant.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: How the PHP will evaluate your if statement: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php --> string, resource or number string, resource or number Translate strings and resources to numbers, usual math ## So the PHP will evaluate something like this: if (intval($real_string) == $string_inted) { /* ... */ }